# Jenkins Pass custom variable to downstream jobs

Tags: jenkins, parameter-passing, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I want to pass a custom variable from Job A to Job B. I have tried achieving this using the "Parameterized Trigger" plugin but I didnt work for me.

I am doing it the following way: 
On Job A:

```
execute shell --> export VAR=1
echo $VAR --> is returning 1
```

Trigger parameterized build on other projects: 
PARAM=${VAR}

On JobB:
I have selected this project is parameterized and declared a variable as PARAM. But when I do execute shell --> echo ${PARAM} it returns be ${VAR} instead of 1.

Am I missing anything here ? Any pointers please ? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a neat way to pass custom variables to downstream job here:

https://sathishpk.wordpress.com/2016/03/01/how-to-passget-parameters-from-shell-command-into-jenkins-other-places/

It worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

That's due to the lifetime of `VAR` is limited within the `Execute shell` step. If you want variable cross step, even cross from Build to Post Action, you can output the variable to a file in `Key = Value` pattern, then read it back in `Parameterized Trigger`